# Added a comment on an answer, then deleted my answer. Was the person having the conversation notified about my last comment?

Tags: discussion, support, comments, deleted-answers

I provided an answer, got into a conversation with the OP and one more user, but then decided to take down my answer, writing one last comment explaining why I decided to do so.

Were those guys notified about my last comment? Obviously they can't reply back, but that's OK.

Comment: If they are using push notifications, they'll receive the notification but will be unable to read the message. Otherwise, I think they won't receive the notification at all. And if they have more than 10k, they'll be able to read the comment anyway, since they'll be able to see the deleted comment (although I do not know if they get the notification in that case). At least that's was my experience as far as I can remember.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about notifying users; that's not what comments are for. You can only ping one person anyway.

Comment: @Gimby comments are for communication, you may be having a conversation with a guy and instead of getting a comment back along with some explanation, you see "answer deleted" leaving you guessing what may have happened. Its not the best way to communicate, is it?

Comment: @yivi thank you for the detailed answer. Personally, i would expect a site with so complicated flows to have a better handling of this scenario, but whatever :)

Comment: Comments are for "communication", but mainly are to ask for clarification or to add more information. They are not really meant to provide a place to have "a conversation". And I think that that is better to consider them to be ephemeral anyway.

Comment: if you want to ping them, just ping them on the question instead.

Comment: @Gimby Not relevant for this question, but is that true? I thought you notify whoever you @ and also the owner of the post you're commenting on, which could notify two users.

Comment: @Clint the owner gets a notification too yes (which is easy to overlook actually), but to me pinging is `@username`.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I'm aware, [only comments from moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231990/284336) that were left within an hour of the post being deleted *should* remain in the inbox after the post they're on is deleted - and this may be limited to comments directed at the OP of the post.

Comments from anyone else will be removed from the inbox and the only way the user will be aware of them is if they happened to see the comment *before* the post was deleted or if they get notifications on their phone (as through one of the Stack Exchange apps), which will display in the lock screen. Even then, they will probably only see half of the comment if it was very long depending on the way they have their notifications set up and the notifications will often disappear after the app is opened.

If they happen to check back in on the post and they have 10k reputation, they will be able to see the comment you left, as comments aren't removed when the post is deleted.

Comment: I don't know if this is a 10k thing but I have [this message for a deleted post](https://imgur.com/a/zI2q4GT) in my inbox. The post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50544148/unable-to-use-boolean-selector-on-pandas-series-with-datetimeindex).

Comment: Huh... interesting... I swear I've tested this before and not been able to see comment notifications for non-mods in the past on deleted posts. I guess I should do some more digging.

Comment: So... @user2285236 Maybe it *is* because you're 10k? When I deleted this answer, your comment notification disappeared. Hmmm. It could also be a bug of some sort.

Comment: Hmm that's strange. Because you can see your own deleted post even if you are not above 10k right? By the same logic, yours should stay in your inbox too.

Comment: Yep... I think that, unless that comment was written by a mod, that's a bug of some sort. The link I've just added to Oded's MSE answer specifically states that you shouldn't see comments from non-mods on deleted posts.

Comment: I've gotten comments in my inbox that are on deleted things that I can't see, bugs me when its long and I can't see all of it. :(

Comment: I've long had a theory that comments you've seen in your inbox remain there when a post is deleted, but comment notifications that are "unread" are removed. Came by that theory after 1) finding comments from deleted posts in my inbox, after I'd already read them in the inbox and 2) seeing the "1" on the icon, clicking it, and seeing nothing new, only to find a post I'd been commenting on had been deleted shortly before I clicked the icon.

Comment: We tested this [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304893/viewed-deleted-comments-staying-in-inbox) and found that comments (possibly just the latest one) will stay in the inbox on a deleted post, but notifications disappear altogether when the comment itself is deleted.